# Return value from a function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an html which has a form that a user could enter url if the value of the input text has www. in it i will create a variable and return it to the function then pass it to the ajax but it seems that when I check it(ajaxData var) in the console it says undefined.

```
<form action="" id="defaultForm">
  <input type="text" id="url">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
   function myreturnValue() {
      $('#defaultForm').submit(function () {

         var w = 'www.';
         var current = $('#url').val();
         var appendW = w + current;

         if (current.match('www.')) {
            console.log('it already consists of www');
            var returnValue = 'site_url:' + current; //site_url:www.domain.com or http://
            console.log(typeof returnValue);
            return returnValue;
         } else {
            var returnValue = 'site_url:' + appendW; //www+url
            console.log(current);
            console.log(appendW);
            console.log(returnValue);
            return returnValue;
         }
      }); //end submit
   }
   var ajaxData = myreturnValue();
   console.log(typeof ajaxData);
   var data = 'data:{' + ajaxData + '}';
});
```

then in the ajax I will pass the data variable. I hope my explanation is kinda clear.

Comment: It seems you are calling the function on this line (...var ajaxData = myreturnValue();...) which calls the parent function but within that function the variable is waiting for the form submit - so the variable does not exist yet. Should probably rejig the function call and order of action.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @gavgrif I will try to rejig it.It makes sense too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in your code, `myreturnValue` function only execute a code to register an event listener to your form, without return value (your return statement will only be triggered on `submit` event), so that's why it will return undefined at the first time.

Try this:

- Put your url detect logic in `myreturnValue` function
- Then put a code to prevent default submit event to be fired
- Finally register a event listener for submit button.

And your original regex `www.` means match www with one other character, like wwww. and www0. will be valid. You may consider changing it to other regex like [this one](https://regex101.com/library/kX6uO2)

```js
$(function() {
  function myreturnValue() {
    var w = 'www.';
    var current = $('#url').val();
    var appendW = w + current;
    if (current.match(w)) {
      console.log('it already consists of www');
      var returnValue = 'site_url:' + current; //site_url:www.domain.com or http://
      console.log(typeof returnValue);
      return returnValue;
    } else {
      var returnValue = 'site_url:' + appendW; //www+url
      console.log(current);
      console.log(appendW);
      console.log(returnValue);
      return returnValue;
    }
  }
  $('#defaultForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var data = 'data:{' + myreturnValue() + '}';
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="defaultForm">
  <input type="text" id="url">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh! I have also the prevent default but I didn't include it here because it doesn't work in mine before, thanks for the regex!

Answer (score 0):

A few problems here.

Calling `$('#defaultForm').submit(function () {` binds a submit handler to the form. It does not submit the form nor execute the function. Please familiarize yourself [with the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Your `myreturnValue()` doesn't return anything. You only have one top level line which is the above submit binding. Not only is it not executed, but `return` inside that function does not propagate up like you're expecting it to. Returning inside an event handler won't do anything in any context.

Don't declare `vars` inside `if` branches in general.

Here's a quick attempt to reorganize this code, but with this many problems the corrected code may depend on your specific needs.

```
(function () {
    $('#defaultForm').submit(function (event) {

        // prevent default form submit
        event.preventDefault();

        var w = 'www.';
        var current = $('#url').val();
        var appendW = w + current;
        var value;

        if (current.match('www.')) {
            console.log('it already consists of www');
            value = 'site_url:' + current; //site_url:www.domain.com or http://
            console.log(typeof returnValue);
        } else {
            value = 'site_url:' + appendW; //www+url
            console.log(current);
            console.log(appendW);
            console.log(returnValue);
        }

        var data = 'data:{' + ajaxData + '}';

        // Do whatever you want with data here

    });

    // If you want to now submit the form by hand...
    $('#defaultForm').submit();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but may I ask is it a bad practice to declare vars in if statements?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the myreturnValue() is only return the returnValue of the function in Submit. 'myreturnValue' function return anything because it doesn't any return value.

You executed unnecessary function to get the ajaxData.
To get the ajaxData, You only need to

```
$('#defaultForm').submit(function () {
    contents
}
```

If fix the code simple...

```
$('#defaultForm').submit(function () {
  var returnValue;
  var w = 'www.';
  var current = $('#url').val();
  var appendW = w + current;

  if (current.match('www.')) {
    console.log('it already consists of www');
    returnValue = 'site_url:' + current;   //site_url:www.domain.com or http://
    console.log(typeof returnValue);
  } else {
    returnValue = 'site_url:' + appendW; //www+url
    console.log(current);
    console.log(appendW);
    console.log(returnValue);
  }
  console.log(typeof returnValue);
  var data = 'data:{' + ajaxData + '}';
  console.log('data : ', data)
});
```

Please, Note : http://codepen.io/onyoon7/pen/mRdJJV